# Angular 12 - Redirect users based upon roles

Tags: angular

I have a scenario
where Admin role login will have access to Home and UserView Component.
By default Admin will go to Home component after login.
User role login will have access to UserView component only and should be redirected to Userview component after login.

I have used canactivate but confused on how to redirect users basis upon role
as per above condition there will be 2 home pages (Home(for admin role) and UserView(for user role) component).

Comment: Please share your `auth guard` and `routing` code.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, hope you get user role in your login api response. You need to redirect user to particular view base to their role.

```
login() {
        this.authenticationService.login(this.email, this.password).subscribe((response: any) => {
                this.authenticationService.getAccountData().subscribe((res: any) => {
                    this.authority = res.authorities[0]; // role
                    this.sharedService.setUserRole(this.authority);
                    if (this.authority === Role.ADMIN_ROLE) {
                        this.router.navigate(['admin/home']);
                    } else if (this.authority === Role.USER_ROLE) {
                        this.router.navigate(['user/home']);
                    } 
                });
            
        });
 }
```

To restrict rout you need to create auth guard in which you need to implement logic to check role for requested route.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, Route } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AdminAuthGuardService {
  constructor(
    private sharedService: SharedService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }
  canActivate(route: Route): boolean {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        if (event.url === '/' || event.url === '/login') {
          if (this.sharedService.getRole() === Role.ADMIN_ROLE) {
            return true;
          } else{
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then use this AdmiAuthGuard in youre routing file

```
path: 'admin',
canActivate: [AdminAuthGuardService],
children: [
    {
       path: 'home',
       loadChildren: '' // add chile module path
     },
]
```

Comment: Hi 
i have done the above
but problem is for UserView there is no button and when we browse through direct url of UserView it refreshes the page thrice and then loads it